# Is it true that there is no CSS @keyframes events? Then we have to break one animation down to several animations and use delay to line them up?

Tags: css, css-animations

It seems there is no CSS `@keyframes` events?  That's because `@keyframes` can provide quite an easy list of actions or transitions to be performed.

If there is no CSS `@keyframes` events but we have to use the `animationend` event, then it seems we have to break down one animation into two or more animations, and line them up using `animation-delay`:

```
animation: 3s 0s animation01, 3s 3s animation02;
```

(the second animation delayed for 3 seconds so that it will happen after `animation01`) to make them happen one after another, for whatever number of animations there are. But then what really belong to one animation will have to be broken down into multiple animations.

Or are there better methods to do this?

Comment: yes it's true. There is such thing in SVG by the way.

Comment: @TemaniAfif how come SVG is related? there are actually events related to SVG rendering? (looks like there are `onbegin, onend, onrepeat`

Comment: it's not related but in the SVG world we can do such thing so maybe you can consider it instead of CSS combined with JS in order to achieve your goal (related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin)

Comment: @TemaniAfif oh you mean there *are* such keyframes events in SVG...